# using \input and pygmentize together: trying to get line numbers to show

Tags: lyx, verbatim, input

I am using pygments to highlight the code I insert in my lyx document.

The external file gets inserted in my document like this:

```
{\small \input{listings/blah.tex} }
```

And I use this command to generate the `blah.tex` file:

```
pygmentize -f latex -O linenos=true -l xml blah.xml > blah.tex
```

I can see that the numbering flags seem to appear in the output of pygmentize:

```
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\{\},numbers=left,firstnumber=1,stepnumber=1]
```

But when I render the pdf, it only shows the highlighted listing, without line numbers. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there anyway you could post a short sample of the `blah.tex` file that pygmentize produces that demonstrates your problem? Have you considered using the `minted` (http://ctan.org/pkg/minted) package? (I know next to nothing about lyx, so this may be an absurd suggestion - apologies).

Comment: This question seems to be related to [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19324/215) (Neither has a satisfactory answer as yet...)

Comment: As I've comment on the question @Seamus links to, this seems to be working fine with an up-to-date system. If the linked question is closed, then this one should be also.